# Difference between String() and ""

Tags: swift, string

Basically what´s the difference between `String()` and `""`

```
var x = "Test"
x = String()
x = ""
```

Will there be any difference between these two lines above?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html), the strings are equivalent:

> **Initializing an Empty String**
>
> To create an empty String value as the starting point for building a longer string, either assign an empty string literal to a variable, or initialize a new String instance with initializer syntax:
>
> ```
> var emptyString = ""               // empty string literal
> var anotherEmptyString = String()  // initializer syntax
> ```

Comment: I don't know where the downvote is from; this is the right answer.

Answer (score -2):

My understanding is when you set a String literal

`var aString = ""`

will at some point be converted, at least functionally, to

`var aString: String = String("")`

So you're technically adding a meaningless amount of work at compile time, but nothing that should matter in pretty much any circumstance.

Comment: Nonsense. That's a recursive definition. If `""` means `String("")`, then `String("")` must mean `String(String(""))` and eventually you end up infinitely recursing to `String(String(String...""...)))`

Comment: Or it just doesn't do it if it's in a string initializer...? The compiler's not that dumb...

Comment: Then how does it know what to do with the `""`? My point is, your proposed definition of `""` as `String("")` can't work.

Comment: my recommendation would be to use this fancy thing called "programming" e.g., if "" is in between () { don't change it }

Comment: Yep. And that's different from what you said.